# CSS grid: Dynamic column number and not exceeding parent width

Tags: css

How to make grid items fit the container?

If there are more items than fit in the container, then wrap them and add more rows

- The second example should wrap into more than one row
- The grid should center horizontally in the container (equal left/right padding)
- All items must have the same height

https://jsfiddle.net/zLo8jw4d/

```css
section {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}

ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: red;
}

li {
  width: 150px;
  background: yellow;
}

a {
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li><a>item 1</a></li>
    <li><a>item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section>
  <ul>
    <li><a>item 1</a></li>
    <li><a>item 2</a></li>
    <li><a>item 3</a></li>
    <li><a>item 4</a></li>
    <li><a>item 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex is really simpler for your case. If you really need to use CSS Grid, you can use "auto-fit" in your grid-template columns, to make the container fill up with items, or create a new row, if the width is not enough for all your list items.

Also justify-content:center will center your li items, and create an equal x-padding.

```css
section {
  max-width: 80%;
  min-height: 50px;
  background: gray;
}

ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(50px, 150px));
  gap: 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: red;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  width: 150px;
  background: yellow;
}

a {
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ul>
    <li><a>item 1</a></li>
    <li><a>item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>

<section>
  <ul>
    <li><a>item 1</a></li>
    <li><a>item 2</a></li>
    <li><a>item 3</a></li>
    <li><a>item 4</a></li>
    <li><a>item 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

https://codepen.io/aggepap/pen/QWZEdXJ

You can read more about auto-fit and auto-fill [here](https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/)